# Where can I find good examples of Emacs Lisp programming with indirect buffers?

Tags: emacs

The existing emacs mode for [Noweb](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/noweb/) is very old and suffers from a lot of problems.  To either fix the problems or write a new mode calls for knowledge of indirect buffers.  I have found one example, the command `org-mode-tree-to-indirect-buffer`.

Where can I find other good examples for learning how to program Emacs features that use indirect buffers?

Comment: I would also like to understand indirect buffers better, but asking for tutorials or downloads is explicitly discouraged on Stack Overflow. Perhaps you could rephrase your question to ask for an explanation of how to fix a simple piece of example code?

Comment: How about just grepping the Emacs built-in libraries for `make-indirect-buffer` and `clone-indirect-buffer` and `buffer-base-buffer`?  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Indirect-Buffers.html

Comment: You don't say what kind of examples you want, or what you mean by "good". Library [`narrow-indirect.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/narrow-indirect.el) is one library that makes use of indirect buffers. It lets you narrow using an indirect buffer that is a clone of the current buffer (which becomes the base buffer for the clone). See [Narrow Indirect](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/NarrowIndirect). But please see @tripleee's comment. Try to pose a question about something specific that you are trying to do, not just "please point to examples of using indirect buffers."

Answer (score 0):

An interesting use-case should be here:

https://github.com/phillord/lentic